# Why would git log not find path specified as "-- ."

Tags: git

I have a rather higgledy-piggledy git repo with several different small directories for different stuff. (Yes, I know that's not best practice, but one gets better at this as time goes by.)

If I change into one of my directories and do this:

```
D:\Repository\ALCS.Work\Brent.WiP\LateX\SysConf.Manual>git log --stat -n 1 -- .
```

I get no output. But when I remove the path, I get a commit listing:

```
D:\Repository\ALCS.Work\Brent.WiP\LateX\SysConf.Manual>git log --stat -n 1
commit 87dce9788dfdf5a26b2ce1429391f72dab456f34 (HEAD -> Brent, origin/master, origin/Brent, master)
Author: Brent Longborough <brent.longborough@ibm.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 21 19:27:13 2019 +0100

    ALCS Configuration Reference - Improved indices, list of figures, ongoing writing

 .gitignore                                         |   1 -
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/.latexmkrc          |   1 +
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/Fig.ComGen.tex      |   4 +-
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/Fig.ComList.tex     |   4 +-
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/Fig.Comol.tex       |   4 +-
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/Fig.Genflow.tex     |   4 +-
 .../LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/Object.Catalogue.tex      |  63 ++--
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/Preamble.tex        |  41 ++-
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/SysConf.Manual.ist  |   7 +
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/SysConf.Manual.tex  | 356 ++++++++++++---------
 Brent.WiP/LaTeX/SysConf.Manual/Table.Summary.tex   |   4 +-
 11 files changed, 287 insertions(+), 202 deletions(-)

D:\Repository\ALCS.Work\Brent.WiP\LateX\SysConf.Manual>
```

Could someone, please, suggest what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Adding a pathspec enables history simplification (search for this term in `git log` documentation or using `[git] history simplification` in the SO search bar). In this case, though, it seems like you should still see that first commit: it's not a merge, and it's the one found by `HEAD`, and it affects the current directory.

Comment: Yes , that was my impression. I'm wondering whether there's something weird in my repo...